# Summary of Workflow History over Time

Tags: sql-server, workflow, powerquery, summary

I am collecting data using a web formular and a workflow with four different status.

1. Started
2. Review by Admin
3. Back to User
4. Finished

Status 2 and 3 are repeated as long as it is needed. The application logs the history of this process and I would like to be able so see the development of the workflow over time.

The history is stored in an MS SQL Table and I can rearange it to look like this.

[image]

In the example there are two workflows (id 1 and 2) and over time the formular goes back and forth untill it is finished. I can order this by time
[image]

to derive the result I would like to have.

[image]

I dont need to have this result in wide format as long as the counting in long is correct.

I am struggling to find a way to avoid double counting status 2 and 3 and also I dont want to count status 1 later on.

I am rather looking for a strategy to obtain my desired results either in SQL or Power Query.
I tried different grouping, dense_rank and other transformations in Power Query.

Comment: How do you get to that result? There is a Finished at 3/1/20 22:00 but not one at 3/1/20 11:00 in the source data.  So why is there a 1 in the output under finished for 3/1/20 11:00?

Comment: I am counting manually by going from step to step ordered by time. There is a finsihed in 2/1/20 22:01, thats when I put 1 in the finished column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in PowerQuery, assumes already date sorted

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Datum", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "zStarted", each if [Status]="Started" then 1 else if [Status]="Review by Admin" then -1 else 0),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "zReview", each if [Status]="Review by Admin" then 1 else if [Status]="Back to User" then -1 else if [Status]="Finished" then -1 else 0),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "zBackA", each if [Status]="Back to User" then 1 else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom2",{"zBackA"}),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "zBackB", each if [zBackA]=null then 0 else if [Status]="Back to User" then 1 else if [Status]="Review by Admin" then -1 else 0),
#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "zFinished", each if [Status]="Finished" then 1 else 0),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
// cumulative sum, converting to zero if <0
#"Cum1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Started", each List.Max(List.Combine({{0}, {List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[zStarted],[Index]+1))}}))),
#"Cum2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Cum1", "Review By Admin", each List.Max(List.Combine({{0}, {List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[zReview],[Index]+1))}}))),
#"Cum3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Cum2", "Back to User", each List.Max(List.Combine({{0}, {List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[zBackB],[Index]+1))}}))),
#"Cum4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Cum3", "Finished", each List.Max(List.Combine({{0}, {List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[zFinished],[Index]+1))}}))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Cum4,{"ID","zStarted", "zReview", "zBackA", "zBackB", "zFinished", "Index","Status"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

| ID | Datum | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06/24/22 | Started |
| 2 | 06/25/22 | Started |
| 1 | 06/26/22 | Review by Admin |
| 2 | 06/27/22 | Review by Admin |
| 1 | 06/28/22 | Back to User |
| 1 | 06/29/22 | Review by Admin |
| 2 | 06/30/22 | Back to User |
| 1 | 07/01/22 | Back to User |
| 1 | 07/02/22 | Review by Admin |
| 2 | 07/03/22 | Review by Admin |
| 1 | 07/04/22 | Finished |
| 2 | 07/05/22 | Back to User |
| 2 | 07/06/22 | Review by Admin |
| 2 | 07/07/22 | Finished |

Comment: thx that seems to work. I still dont understand it. I needed to allign the spelling for "Back to / To User". Ill accept on Moday if nobody has another solution

Comment: The code is fairly simple to read as to what it is doing. Did you step through and see what it is doing? What questions did you have.  Its just creating 4 columns then cumulatively summing them.

Comment: I just need some time that I didn't have yet. I actually need to add one grouping variable. I guess I do understand the logic and might to the same with case in sql and just add a grouping

Comment: thanks again I alsow found my own solution in SQL based on your input

Comment: sorry forgot :) please do so as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @horseyride i came up with my own solution using case and a similar approach within SQL

I follow a three step appraoch to avoid the double counting of changes in status by using the lagged status (sql columne action_nam)
With the lagged status I can then unambigously define the changes of the status and take the cumulutive sum.

I mark the first answer as accepted as this one helped me to find my own solution. I leave my solution with the Germany Status names just for completeness

```
Select top 600 created, form_uuid,  Cum_Erstellt, Cum_Review, Cum_Korrektur, Cum_Fertig from (
Select *,
 sum(Erstellt) over(Partition by form_uuid order by  form_uuid, created) as Cum_Erstellt,
  sum(Review) over(Partition by form_uuid order by  form_uuid, created) as Cum_Review,
  sum(Korrektur) over(Partition by form_uuid order by  form_uuid, created) as Cum_Korrektur,
  sum(Fertig) over(Partition by form_uuid order by  form_uuid, created) as Cum_Fertig,
  Erstellt+Review+Korrektur+Fertig as Vergleich
from (
Select  created, form_uuid, encoded_key, action_name, lag_action, 
    CASE WHEN action_name = 'Datensatz erstellt und zur Bearbeitung an Datenlieferanten übergeben' THEN 1
        When action_name = 'Datensatz zur Prüfung an Datensammler' and 
        lag_action='Datensatz erstellt und zur Bearbeitung an Datenlieferanten übergeben' THEN -1 
        Else 0 END AS Erstellt,
        CASE WHEN action_name = 'Datensatz zur Prüfung an Datensammler' THEN 1
        When action_name= 'Datensatz zur Korrektur an Datenlieferanten' Then -1 
        when Action_name= 'Datensatz erneut Öffnen' then 1
        When action_name='Datensatz durch Datensammler bestätigt' Then -1
        Else 0 END AS Review,
        CASE
        WHEN action_name = 'Datensatz zur Prüfung an Datensammler' and
        lag_action!='Datensatz erstellt und zur Bearbeitung an Datenlieferanten übergeben'  THEN -1
        When action_name= 'Datensatz zur Korrektur an Datenlieferanten'  Then 1
        Else 0 END AS Korrektur,
        CASE WHEN action_name = 'Datensatz durch Datensammler bestätigt' THEN 1
        When action_name= 'Datensatz erneut Öffnen' Then -1
        Else 0 END AS Fertig
from (
Select created, form_uuid, encoded_key, action_name, lag(action_name,1,NULL)
over( order by  encoded_key,  form_uuid, created)  as lag_action
from process_instance_hist ) lag_table
) change_table
) cum_table 
order by created, encoded_key
--group by created, form_uuid
```